# Comparing large xml files

Tags: windows, file, diff

could anyone assist me with this.
I need to compare two beefy xml files 40mb each (ok not that beefy), but notepad++ croaks on this.
Can anyone suggest something that will help (windows only).

I read a similar thread:
[Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

but this only talks about opening large files. Comparing and opening are 2 very different animals.
Can anyone suggest anything that will help

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always use [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) or [ExamDiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) (Pro version) for my Diff needs. I haven't tried them with files larger than 2 MB, but you might want to give them a try.

Comment: diffmerge is going like a boeing.
Thanks!

Comment: After notepad++ let me show bluescreen during comparison of two 13mb files, diffmerge did the job :)

Comment: DiffMerge can't handle 1.4GB files :(

Comment: DiffMerge crashes with 60-90Mb files

Answer (score 4):

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\fc.exe <firstfile> <secondfile>
```

? :)

Comment: This is slow but it is producing a text file

Answer (score 3):

- http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm (command line)
- http://winmerge.org/ (GUI)

Answer (score 0):

[kDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) worked fine for me to compare files greater than 10 MB - It's quite light-weight.

Comment: When I compared 2 files 1GB each, it crashed my WinExplorer so hard I had to power cycle the box.

Comment: For me it could not handle files with a size of 100MB

Answer (score 0):

I use WinDiff for such a purpose. It was installed on my windows7 machine and comes from Microsoft (so its free). It's 64Bit application and performs very well.

Answer (score 0):

Could easily compare with vs code. no need to download plugins or anything, comes with the default package. Just drag and drop the files you want to compare and select the option as compare with selected. 
[image]

Comment: It does not work for big files, tried for a file of size 80 MB.