# Display lines in the middle of the log file

Tags: file, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux text editor for working with huge files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591723/linux-text-editor-for-working-with-huge-files)

I have a log file with more 200,000 lines. How can i see the lines from 4500 to 5000. I am not sure vi editor opens up such a huge file. Please help

Comment: If you have the ram on your PC, it should open it up fine.  Otherwise, you can make a little Perl/Python/C app that you pipe the file into along with a range of lines you'd like to output.  If you're lazy and the lines are numbered, just use the "more" command and hold space bar for a while :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '4500,5000{p}' log.file
```

then you can either pipe it to less or > to a new file.

Answer (score 3):

`vi` can open such files. That's the reason that makes `vi` such an amazing editor.
But you can display your file with `head -n 5000 hugefile.txt | tail -n 500`

Comment: oh ok, i didnt know. i think the combination of head and tail command is also a good one

Comment: Kent solution is a better one. Sed may not open the whole 5000 line to output only 500 of those.

Comment: which one is a better in terms of cpu usage b/w vi editor and head|tail? any idea. i dont want my command that takes all the cpu

Comment: For 5000 lines, neither of the both will over-use the CPU. But Kent solution's is the better one.

Comment: the head | tail one should not work. head -n 4500 gives the first 4500 lines, and tail -n 5000 gives the last 5000 lines from input. in your command, the result would be 1-4500 lines. but OP wants 4500-5000 lines. am I right?

Comment: @Kent That's why i edited my answer 4 minutes ago ;D This now works. But as I said, your solution is the better one.

Comment: thx. just noticed your edit..