# how to handle large text files?

Tags: large-files

I have a file which contains around 10 million rows and size is around 400mb , my system is just not able to handle it . when i try opening the file using gedit , it just gets stuck . Is there any way to handle such large files of data.

Comment: Handle how? What do you want to do?

Comment: Assuming that you don't want to write a program to do that, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files  Does this belong on superuser?

Comment: For anyone else who doesn't know, 1 crore = 10,000,000

Comment: @DOK: Agreed, but to be fair, there are only five other questions of which he's accepted an answer on one. (The seventh is this one, and one of the other six has been closed.) @Rahul: 20% still isn't good and suggests either that your questions are not sufficiently detailed or answerable, or that people *have* answered them but you haven't marked an answer.

Comment: @DOK :ohh sorry .. i would definitely do that . i  apologise since i am new to the committee, it will take a while being accustomed to it .

Comment: @user67011 well vim is  doing great . should have used that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split them using the gnu (cygwin on Windows) head, tail or cut utilities. Then do work on the file parts.

Comment: well this file is generated from a tool where i can test db performance . it basically a csv file . is there any way i can split depending upon no of rows i want.

Answer (score 2):

A web based great utility that can handle large file is Google Refine Tool.

You can find https://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/FaqAllocateMoreMemory  [details for memory allocation]

Comment: The OP mentions `gedit`, so they just want to look at the content of a text file, not transform it.

Answer (score 1):

A great utility for Windows is [Large Text Viewer](http://www.swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html)

I was able to open a file over 4GB in size.

Comment: well i work mostly in ubuntu . thanks . but vim itself did a neat job .

Comment: Well say that in your question.

Comment: Fully recommended in Windows