# Logfile editor with good regex support

Tags: windows, regex, editor

I am tangling with a project involving enormous text log files on the server and it is getting logistically difficult moving files around so I can get at them with my main programming editors.  It has become clear that I need to install editors on the servers.  Installing full devel tools is out of the question, and frankly, I'm a bit stumped as I guess I've mostly been using Visual Studio and Eclipse so long I just don't know much about the current state of editors out there.

I sure bet someone here on StackOverflow does!

I need something that can deal with large (multi GB) text files with efficiency and decent multiline regular expression support is a must.  Other than those features, minimum footprint and bloat is better than more features.  Windows Server 2008 R2.  Of course free, or really reasonable price like shareware.  Anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

Comment: Good tip, Cheeso, but mnojlds answer below actually makes this a valuable reference page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Log Parser:

> Log parser is a powerful, versatile
>   tool that provides universal query
>   access to text-based data such as log
>   files, XML files and CSV files, as
>   well as key data sources on the
>   Windows® operating system such as the
>   Event Log, the Registry, the file
>   system, and Active Directory®.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

I have used it for parsing huge log files

Some examples: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910447

Comment: Thanks, manojlds!  I did not know about this tool.  I downloaded it and am looking at it now.

Comment: this Log Parser is cool, the feature to make HTML pages is going to make my support people happy clams.  Thanks very much.  There is a whole book on it -- now on my Kindle!