# Edit huge sql data file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a 23GB file and I would like to edit the 23rd line, but I have only 200 MB RAM available on the server. I do not want to open the file entirely because I have left only 20GB available disk space.

How can I do this. I tried to use head, tail sed but it seems it creates a temporary file. Is it possible to do it without a temporary file?

Comment: Did you try sed with edit in place?

Comment: Most (all?) seds, GNU sed among them, use a temporary file for `-i`.

Comment: Is that a temporary file or a backup file?

Comment: It reads from one file, writes to the other, then removes the original (unless it's instructed to keep a backup) and renames the new file to the old name.

Comment: Perhaps you could adapt the trick from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/378230/how-can-i-compress-a-file-on-linux-in-place-without-using-additional-disk-space), as in `sed '23s/foo/bar/' filename | dd of=filename conv=notrunc` (and truncate to the new length afterwards if the resulting file is shorter). **Test that before you use it on live data. You do have a backup, right? Right?!**

Comment: You rent a virtual machine, copy the 23GB file to it, edit it, check it, delete the original, and then copy the edited file back to the original location.  Alternatively you buy some more storage hardware.

Comment: also sed '23 {s/foo/bar; q}' where q is quit can be reconsidered

Comment: You can see this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place) that uses `dd` as in the @Wintermute example

Comment: @josifoski a quit will stop to ouptut the lines after 23 so, new file will only have 23 lines at the end, not an option in this case

Comment: Hmm...come to think of it, does the `dd` trick have a change of working if the transformation makes the file larger? Another thought: Compress the file, then `zcat` it through `sed`, i.e., `gzip file; zcat file.gz | sed '23s/foo/bar/' > file`. You might have enough space for that left.

Comment: copying part of file on usb, deleting that part of bigfile, using sed, some hdd memory will be freed or using that overwrite.c idea or  best using better hardware

Comment: Use c/c++. Seek to the position, write whatever you want. close the file ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17331179/1745001 for another use of `dd` (your only hope).

Comment: The answer to the following question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353536/emacs-to-read-large-files-14gb/8353828#8353828

Comment: Will the revised file have a 23rd line that is bigger, smaller, or the same size as the original?  You can write code to handle any of the three cases (same size is easiest).  Whether there's a standard tool suitable is considerably more debatable.  You definitely need a back-up of some sort.  Are you sure you can't compress some other files on the system and give yourself enough space to work in?  Can't you get new disk space for the machine?  (I'm guessing, given the mention of 200MiB memory, that it is an antique on its last legs and not expandable any more.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to edit the file with a hex editor. Hex editors are built to handle huge files, even whole disks and partitions.

You may find [hexedit](http://www.rogoyski.com/adam/programs/hexedit/) (ncurses based) or [ghex](https://developer.gnome.org/ghex/) (Gnome/Gtk based) useful. They are common utilities, therefore you will most probably find them in your distributions's repo.

All hex editors I have used, use a twin panel view with the left panel showing the bytes of the file in Hex, and the right panel trying to show an Ascii representation when that is possible.

In order to find and edit your 23rd line:

`sed -n '23p' my_huge_dump.sql` : Will print the contents of this line
`sed -n '23p' my_huge_dump.sql | od -A n -t x1` : Will print the contents of this line in hexadecimal format.

or open the file with `less -N my_huge_dump.sql` and view the contents of line 23. (`-N` in `less` enables line numbering)

Now, knowing the content of the 23rd line:

- If the text of this line is somewhat unique and different from surrounding lines, you may find it from the right (ascii) panel and navigate to this line with the arrows. In `hexedit` you use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move between the Hex and Ascii panels. In gHex you can use your mouse as well. You may also search for the string you're interested: Move to the Ascii panel and press <kbd>/</kbd> in `hexedit` or use the menu in gHex.
- If the line you want to edit has similar contents to other lines and you can't find it in the ascii panel, then you must count the "newline" separators to find the 23rd line. New lines (LF) are represented as `0A` in hex. In the ASCII panel, new lines are represented as dots `.`

Then assuming you found the line you want to edit, you have the following options:

- Hopefully, the new content of the 23rd line is shorter or equal in length to the existing content (so you won't need to grow and move the whole file). In this case, you have to enter the `Fill-mode` i.e. the mode in which you overwrite existing content typing over the old text. This is the default mode in both `gHex` and `hexedit`. Move to the location you want to edit and start typing. Pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will undo your changes. If the new content is shorter than the existing, you may fill up the line with spaces to avoid truncating the file.
- If the new content is longer than the existing one in this line, then you have to enter the `Insert` mode. You can do that using the Menu in gHex. In `hexedit` you have to use the <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> keybinding. Then start typing and the new characters will be appended in the current location.

In the first case, it is guaranteed that the editing and saving of the file will be instantaneous since an in-place edit will happen. In the later case, I'm not sure how the growing in size and the moving of following bytes will be handled, but I hope the filesystem uses a larger non-continuous block to move some of the contents and not move the whole file.

If you're happy with your changes, save the file:

- Use the menu in gHex
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> in `hexedit` and answer `(Y)es` when questioned about whether to save the changes.

Always make sure you have a backup in place!

EDIT: I found out that `gHex` isn't  suitable for your situation, since it tries to load the whole file in memory. `hexedit` will serve you fine. However, if you want a graphical editor like `gHex`, but with partial file loading capabilities, you may try [wxHexEditor](http://www.wxhexeditor.org/home.php). Check also the [Comparison of Hex editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors) page in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Liquid Studio Community Edition contains a [Large File Editor](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/large-file-editor) which can open and edit Terra-byte files on low spec machines, and its free.

It requires enough disk space to copy the file (when writing it back out), but hardly requires any memory.

[image: Liquid Studio Large File Editor]