# Sed replace first occurence in place with big files

Tags: unix, replace, sed

I have got around 50 big text files (~4GB) and I only need to replace one string situated in the first 100 lines of these files. In fact what I would need is an unix command line that look for the first match, replace it in place and break.

I've tried playing with sed but I'm still struggling to get a satisfying result.

Comment: Somehowr related: [How to edit 300 GB text file (genomics data)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16900721/1983854).

Comment: Also somewhat similar [Edit huge SQL data file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727191).  That file's about 23 GiB on a machine with 20 GiB free space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit up to the first match using `sed`:

```
sed -e '1,/pattern/{s/pattern/replace/;}'
```

On lines 1 to N-1 (where line N contains the pattern), the substitution does nothing; on line N, it does the real work.  Thereafter, you're no longer in the `1,/pattern/` range of lines so there is no further transformation.

Note that this doesn't work if line 1 matches the pattern; it then makes changes in line 1 and the next line that matches the pattern.  With GNU `sed` at least, you can change the `1` to `0` and that works OK.

```
printf "%s\n" pattern pattern pattern pattern |
sed -e '0,/pattern/{s/pattern/replace/;}'
```

However, the description says "in the first 100 lines" and while line 1 is in the first 100 lines, that isn't the way you'd normally describe it when it appears on line 1.

You can add a `-i` option to overwrite the original file once you've tested it.  Beware: not all versions of `sed` support `-i` and on Mac OS X, the backup suffix is mandatory `-i.bak` (but can be empty: use `-i ''`).  By contrast, GNU `sed` has an optional suffix which must be attached to the `-i` option.  Hence, `-i.bak` works with both GNU and Mac (BSD) `sed`; other uses of the `-i` option are specific to the variant of `sed` you're using.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '1,100 { :a; N; $! ba; s/input/output/ }' file
```

- `:a; N; $! ba` is appending first 100 lines in pattern space
- all 100 lines will be treated like one string.
- Then substitution will take care only on first matched pattern.
- `-i` is inplace editing

`q` can't be used after replacement since it will stop printing the rest of the lines.

Also before executing above sed i'll recommend checking is pattern string inside file and where with

```
sed -n '/patternstring/{=;p}' file
```

where = is printing line number (some grep styled sed command)

or if you want to quit imidiatelly after finding first match

```
sed -n '/patternstring/{=;p;q}' file
```

Comment: I just tried this on a 500-line input, and it had no effect whatsoever. Which is odd, because I was expecting a completely different failure mode.

Comment: let me check in practice, needs something more + in appending 100 lines

Comment: Now it should work, i've added $! which will always be true, so first 100 lines will be appending

Comment: No, it's just editing the first hundred lines in place and passing the rest unchanged, you don't need all that fancy. Just `'1,100 s/input/output/'`

Comment: it will reflect on all 100 lines if string is more than once present in them, with my solution only on first matched input string

Comment: Also, since this is "Unix", not "Linux", it bears mentioning that the "`-i`" option for editing in place is not supported by POSIX, (see [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html](here)), and that POSIX doesn't allow for labels to be followed by other commands on the same line.

Comment: Ah. Missed the only-match-first clause. Still, the initial solution had no effect in my test.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to treat the first occurence without knowing exactly where it is, you could use `ed`. It is a very old line editor written in the time where memory was scarce. It may be a little less efficient than sed here but both simpler and more robust against the pattent not being exactly where expected.

```
echo '/input/s/input/output/
wq' | ed file
```