# which editor or IDE are you using when one file is over 20000 lines?

Tags: javascript, ide, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

I'm editing an javascript library file which is over 20000 lines, I tried both **notepad++** and **Aptana**, but they are too slow(particularly Aptana, an Undo operation will cosume 10 seconds)

So which editor or IDE are you using if the file is a little large?

Comment: I use the Zeus editor and it handles big files very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime text 2 can manage that huge quantity of lines:
http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Comment: thanks, really fast and some amazing features

Comment: I tried sublime text - it failed to open a 500MB SQL text file.  Heidisql opens it, but runs too slowly.  notepad++ just says no

Comment: http://www.ultraedit.com/ worked for me with a massive text file where the other suggested editors failed.

Answer (score 0):

I use gedit. I've never had the need to edit 20,000 lines however. But gedit is able to cope pretty well with large amounts of code.

Answer (score 0):

For File size >20000 lines i believe **[Slick edit](http://www.slickedit.com)** (http://www.slickedit.com/)is the best option...
in my organisation we used slickedit of analysing log files of >25000 lines..
it is fastest editor for such a huge file only disadvantage is you have to pay for it...

Answer (score 0):

Try WEbStorm - it is good IDE to edit JS. I tried jquery-1.7.1 (about 10K lines) on my old notebook - works fine and comfortable

Comment: I really do not understand why people are behind WebStorm, I have used it and could not find it better than Brackets.io. And WebStorm is not faster for large files, it sucks. But Brackets.io is not meant for large files, it slows down everything when you load large files.