# How to clear apache_error.log file if this file size greater than 3GB?

Tags: php, apache

In my error log file size is above 3gb.But i unable to clear. Because of cannot open this using any editor.

Comment: Get a better editor then. I suggest EditPad. Or just delete the file.

Comment: rm logfile.log | del logfile.log

Comment: as long as you don't have very long lines you should be able to read it line per line instead of reading it as a whole.

Comment: Use logrotation. You should configure that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I recommend you to use logrotate service for that! Don't just delete the file.

Here is a good tutorial : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/

Comment: As I said .. it is not recommended to delete live apache log files. Use logrotate with the size trimming option.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/) explains how to use log rotate to rotate logs in a linux environment.  You can do something similar in windows also.  This will help with any future logs.

For your 3GB log, you need a specific tool to view files this big.  Most editors choke on large files.  See the answer for [this stackflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files) for more info.

Comment: @giri What do you mean any other method? Any other method to rotate or to view the file? Also, how long did it take to get to this size?