# how to open a large (100GB) .txt file?

Tags: linux, text

I have a .txt file of ~100GB. Is there a text editor that I can use to open this? If so, how will this actually be stored in memory? I only have 16GB of RAM.

I'm also exploring other options such as splitting the file into 2 or more pieces. Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently on the command line in linux?

Thanks

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files?lq=1

Comment: Why is there "duplicate" next to my question? I searched and couldn't find a similar question. Maybe I missed it...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the utilities HEAD and TAIL if using the command line.  Often I will use

```
tail -<number of lines> | more
```

And to split the file look at SPLIT.

Comment: And also the `csplit` command.