# Output Redirection in linux to a file by a variable

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, output-redirect

I have a file pointed to by a user defined environmental variable `$file` defined as:

`file='filename.groovy'`

When I do:

`echo $file`

It prints correctly without any problem as:

`filename.groovy`

and when I do:

`cat $file`

Its successfully printing the content of the file 'filename.groovy'

Everything is perfect till here

But, the *problem* is :

When I'm trying to redirect the output of `sed` command as:

`sed 's/def version = ".*"/def version = "'$version'"/' $file > $file`

and then

> cat $file

Its printing nothing i.e., my original file got **truncated**.

Why is it so ?

Please suggest the reason and solution to redirect the output of `sed` command to the file 'filename.groovy' by using the variable $file

Thanx in advance . . .

Comment: Actually I hit `Tab` and `Enter` accidentally, so my question got submitted before I complete and then I got disconnected. Sorry for that...

Comment: How if we want to redirect that output to a different file pointed to by $file2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read a file and in the meanwhile redirect your output to it.

What you can do is to use `-i` parameter in `sed`, that updates the file:

```
sed -i 's/def version = ".*"/def version = "'$version'"/' $file
```

You can see an example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16901328/1983854 I posted yesterday.

Comment: How if we want to redirect that output to a different file pointed to by $file2 ?

Comment: In that case, `sed 's...' $file1 > $file2` should make the trick.

Comment: Okey.. Thank you. I got it. So, that means the problem arises only if the redirection is meant to the same file. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. Like what I get here: `$ cat a > a
cat: a: input file is output file`.

Answer (score 1):

`>` truncates the file *before* the command is run, but you can use `sed -i` to replace in a file in-place.