# Modify the 'tail' of a document

Tags: shell, unix, tail

I have a very huge txt document (120MB) I would like to modify only a few lines at the end of the document. So far I have done it with Vi - opened the whole document and then scrolled down. But, loading so big documents even with Vi takes a lot of time. Is there a way to select lines in Unix and modify them in a command line shell?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [How to edit 300 GB text file (genomics data)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16900721/1983854). If you know the line numbers, it is quite straight forward.

Comment: I know you can use libc/syscalls/php/ansi c to create a file descriptor, set its cursor to a specific address and only write those bytes. It's called `fseek()`.

Comment: It's straightforward to do with awk, sed, ed, ...  Can you describe exactly what edits you need to make?

Comment: I need to add some ending tags at the end of file [e.g. </body>
</tmx>]

Comment: On modern hardware, opening a 120MB file in Vim shouldn't be a problem.  I use `set noswapfile` and `set nobackup` in my .vimrc file and have no problem opening large files.  Once the file is open, use `G` to jump to the end, and start editing.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies.

Comment: If you're literally only appending to the very end, that's even easier than editing lines near the end in-place: `echo "</body></tmx>" >>file`

Comment: I find so far Charles' reply most attractive. Can you also combine the 'sed' command with 'echo' - for example to replace </body> with </tmx>?

Comment: @user3635159, no need for echo. If you have GNU sed, for instance: `sed -i "s@</body>@</tmx>@"`. That said, that'll change it everywhere in the document; if you know the line number for the single line where it needs changing, though, that can be passed to `sed` too. To only edit the area between the 15,000th line and the end of file, for instance: `sed -i '15000,$s@</body>@</tmx>@'`. If you have a `sed` without GNU extensions, the *standard* (and actually better) tool for this kind of in-place edit is `ex`.

Comment: ...also, you can test `ex` commands in vim interactively, since its commands are the same thing as `vi`'s command-mode operations. (There's actually a good chance that your system's `ex` binary is provided by the `vim` package; I only know of a few Linux distros where it's not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Chopping then Catting

You could always use `split` with any of its various options to make smaller files, then edit the last file, and concatenate them back together with `cat` when you're done.

Or use `csplit`, to chop off only the end piece.

### A Better Way

As [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) points out, it would be more efficient to use `dd` to seek near the end of the file, read the contents and edit them, then use `dd` again to tack it back on.

This is especially important when dealing with really huge files.

### Changing the editor

With Vim you can also do `set noswapfile`, `set nobackup` and `syntax off` to reduce the load of the editor on your system.

Or you could try `vim -u "NONE" file.csv` to use Vim without any plugins.

**Note**: The first two methods assume that you don't know *exactly* (i.e. line number or pattern) where you want to edit yet.

Comment: The split/concat approach is needlessly inefficient, compared to editing in-place; if this is done correctly, there should be no need to rewrite anything prior to the content being edited.

Comment: It could be a fix depending on how large the file is, but you're right.

Comment: ...using `dd` to seek to 2k from the end, read off the content there, modify it in-place, and then dd it back onto the end is perhaps a more reasonable alternative to `split` -- that way you're only rewriting one block at the end of the file, leaving the rest completely in-place. Even then, though, that's still more work than having `ex` or another UNIX tool go straight to the line and modify it for you.

Comment: Sure, or even `csplit` into two then `cat` again would be better than `split` proper.

Comment: Anything that involves `cat` is defeating the point, because it means you're rewriting parts of the file that don't need to change. Pretend it was a 100GB file instead of a 200MB one, and the point is magnified; if you're doing it right, you're modifying only the last block, and not rewriting anything else or consuming space for temporary files beyond your block size (a matter of a few kb).

Comment: ...so, if you tell `dd` to copy out everything after 500 bytes before the file's end, edit that 500-byte file, and then tell `dd` to put the edited version back in place, then you've only modified a single 2k (or 4k, or whatever your filesystem was formatted with) block. Very fast, no temp space usage beyond a single block size. Use some `split` variant to create 200mb of temporary files, and recombine them to rewrite the 200mb target file, and you've done 400mb of IO, instead of 8kb of IO max.