# How to view huge txt files in Linux?

Tags: linux, editor

I have got a **4 GiB** txt file that I need to view.

When I try to open it in *Gedit* it loads for a while and then crashes.

Do you have any ideas for a text editor that I can use to view this file? My OS is *Fedora 20*.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Use the split command. See https://askubuntu.com/a/28861/108176 for details.

Answer (score 57):

**BEHOLD!** Since [glogg](https://github.com/nickbnf/glogg) looks unmaintained [klogg](https://github.com/variar/klogg) is better alternative nowadays

```
apt install klogg
```

---

Try [glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/download.html). It worked great for me.

Debian:

```
apt-get install glogg
```

Fedora:

```
yum install glogg
```

Comment: Best answer so far. Works like a charm.

Comment: @BornToDrink What you said! Great for viewing immense files with zero latency

Comment: Tried glogg on Windows 10 and it is amazing. Perfectly does the job.

Comment: Note that this requires a GUI and isn't a command-line-only tool.

Comment: Glogg seems unmaintained. There is an active fork -- [klogg](https://github.com/variar/klogg)

Comment: Glogg reproducably makes my laptop crash when doing a simple search. Do you need to have, like, 32 GB RAM to use this?

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru - try `klogg` as mentioned in comment above. Also, edited my answer.

Comment: Hm, okay this doesn't crash, but it's still slow. And it doesn't find matches for `^insert` in a mysqldump file. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru dev builds of klogg should be 3-5 times faster than 20.12 release. As for search results, could you open an issue at https://GitHub.com/variar/klogg?

Answer (score 32):

Not text editors, but in the command line `tail -n 100 ./file.txt` will give you the last 100 lines of a file, `head -n 100 ./file.txt` will give you the first 100 lines.

vim in the command line buffers as you read through a file (it doesn't open it in one go) so it's quite effective too.

Comment: ok i'll check out vim. Thanks

Comment: if you're new to vim this is a very handy guide http://www.worldtimzone.com/res/vi.html

Answer (score 24):

You can install *Midnight Commander*.

Debian, Ubuntu, etc.:

```
apt-get install mc
```

Red Hat, CentOS, Fedora, etc.:

```
yum install mc
```

You can start *Midnight Commander* from the *CLI* with the `mc` command.
After that you may select and open any file in "view mode" (<kbd>F3</kbd>) or in "edit mode" (<kbd>F4</kbd>).

`mc` is much more efficient when opening and browsing large files than `vim`. I checked it myself.

If you want to watch a very large file in your favorite editor, without worrying about the limitations associated with RAM, I suggest you split the file using the `split` command:

```
split -n 8 [FILE_NAME]
```

The above cammand splits the file into 8 parts.

Of course, this solution will only check for some applications. Note that not every file retains its consistency after the division (e.g. *XML* does not). It all depends on what you want to do with the given file.

Comment: I do not understand why, someone gave me a negative opinion. Can anyone explain it to me? I tried to give in my opinion the best possible answer, touching issues that did not appear in other responses.

Comment: These methods were useful for solving real problems.

Comment: Please let me know why the ansver is downvoted?

Comment: Sometimes people are weird, nice hints! +1

Answer (score 4):

If viewing is anything you need, you might want to use `less` which should be included with your distribution. I'm frequently viewing terabyte-sized files with it. There are also the variants of `zless` and `bzless` for gzipped/bz2'ed files.

`emacs` should also work with large files (as an alternative to vim).

`nano` is another `vim` alternative I find easier to use for basic tasks in the default configuration. In a short test run, I could successfully view a 1GB file, however opening it took more than 30 seconds (however after that, it seems to run quite smoothly).

Answer (score 1):

I have just encoutered this very problem -- I need to view big log files. I tried gedit but it failed to open. Vim worked but I want to scroll. I also tried to install gglog but it does not provide the function of line wrapping and my logs are jsonlines so the lines are long and the wrapping is imporatant.

So finally, I unexpectedly discovered that it is the easiest to use a web browser. I checked both Firefox and Chromium. They work perfectly. I can scroll quite comfotably through my big logs and even search for words. **So my advice is to use any decent web browser to view such files.**

Comment: I don't know if it is wise to open a 4GB file in a browser. My chrome struggles if I open ~100 MB txt file.

Comment: How do you open a file with web browser anyway? I have 1.7GB tsv (csv line just tab separated), so I drag and drop to Firefox and it wants to download the file

Answer (score 0):

Natpad handles opening big files pretty well. [Natpad 2.5](https://github.com/douwevos/natpad/releases/tag/v2.5)