# Multiple lines in a .csv file do not have same number of elements in R

Tags: r, csv, skip

I am attempting to read a very large .csv file into R

```
OrigTotalPumping <- read.table("/Users/Larry/Desktop/OrigTotalPumping/MasterOrigFt3.csv", 
                               header=F, sep=",")
```

I get an error back

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
>    line 19437 did not have 7 elements

So I tried to simply skip that line, but the same error occurs for multiple lines in the file, and the file is far too large to open and manually fix. For example

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 7 elements
```

and

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 19439 did not have 7 elements
```

How do I set it so it can read in this file despite this problem?

Comment: Well, do you know exactly what's causing that problem? Do you know why that line is shorter than the others?

Comment: why dont you give a try to colclasses parameter to defined no. of columns in your csv.

Comment: You can print the bad line with `scan("MasterOrigFt3.csv", "character", skip=19436, n=1, sep="\n")`

Comment: @MrFlick no I don't; the file is so large I can't even open it to view.

Comment: @user3736201 that's why Flick was suggesting you `scan` just the bad line. R should have no problem doing that. Similarly, you could assign *all* "bad" lines to `baddies` with `txt <- readLines("/Users/Larry/Desktop/OrigTotalPumping/MasterOrigFt3.csv"); baddies <- txt[which(count.fields(textConnection(txt), ',') != 7]`.

Comment: To read in just the lines with 7 fields, you can use: You could do something like: `txt <- readLines("/Users/Larry/Desktop/OrigTotalPumping/MasterOrigFt3.csv"); OrigTotalPumping <- read.csv(text=txt[which(count.fields(textConnection(txt), ',') == 7)], header=FALSE)` (This corrects a typo from my previous, now-deleted comment).

Comment: Didn't see that comment before I replied. I did scan just now and the lines have the same number of elements

Comment: On another note, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/159521/489704) for suggestions of text editors that can open/edit text files whose size is of the order of multiple GB.

Comment: I think I will open it up and have a look in vim but I don't think there's anything to edit from the looks of it... it seems (from looking at specific lines) they have 7 elements?

Comment: Also, maybe try to set `,quote = ""` in `read.table()`. This is what usually causes these types of errors

Comment: @user3736201 Can you edit your question to include the bad line? Is there a `#` or `'` in there? That can be fixed by setting the `quote=` or `comment=` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't skip it, but better put this code under a loop and under a trycatch block. And do a error handling for issued record/records.
How to do trycatch in R:
Here is the link for the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Can you pre-process the file with `awk` like this to create a cleaned-up file where every line has 7 fields?

```
awk 'NF==7' original.csv > cleaned.csv
```

or, if your field separator is a comma

```
awk -F',' 'NF==7' original.csv > cleaned.csv
```

Or, building on @Spacedman's idea, you could use `awk` to just show you "unhappy" lines that don't have 7 fields

```
awk -F',' 'NF!=7 {print "Line " NR $0}' yourfile.csv | more
```

Comment: Sounds FANTASTIC! The field separators are commas, but I got back an empty file after it ran

Comment: Please get a few lines from your file and edit them into your question. Get them like this `head -3 yourfile.csv > sample.csv`

Comment: Better still you can use `awk` to look at the failing lines: `awk 'NR==19437' original.csv` or `awk 'NR>19400' original.csv | more` and figure out whether it has missing commas, quoted commas etc etc. (`NR` in `awk` is "Record Number"). And a half-decent text editor should be able to read in a big CSV file for editing if you have to do it manually.

Comment: @Spacedman Good suggestion, thanks, I have edited (a modification of) it into my answer so all can see without trawling the Comments.