# Reading large csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread, bigdata

I have a number of csv-files of different size, but all somewhat big. Using `read.csv` to read them into R takes longer than I've been patient to wait so far (several hours). I managed to read the biggest file (2.6 gb) very fast (less than a minute) with `data.table`'s `fread`.

My problem occurs when I try to read a file of half the size. I get the following error message:

> Error in `fread("C:/Users/Jesper/OneDrive/UdbudsVagten/BBR/CO11700T.csv"`,:
>
> Expecting 21 cols, but line 2557 contains text after processing all
>   cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having
>   embedded `sep=';'` and/or (unescaped) `'\n'` characters within unbalanced
>   unescaped quotes.
>
> `fread` cannot handle such ambiguous cases and those
>   lines may not have been read in as expected. Please read the section
>   on quotes in ?`fread`.

Through research I've found suggestions to add `quote = ""` to the code, but it doesn't help me. I've tried using the `bigmemory` package, but R crashes when I try. I'm on a 64 bit system with 8 gb of ram.

I know there are quite a few threads on this subject, but I haven't been able to solve the problem with any of the solutions. I would really like to use `fread` (given my good experience with the bigger file), and it seems like there should be some way to make it work - just can't figure it out.

Comment: seems to be an issue with what's inside `CO11700T.csv` not so much with size

Comment: Hi your best bet is to have a look at line 2557 maybe using bash or similar e.g. `head -2557 C011700.csv | tail -1` and cut it or edit it manually

Comment: @StephenHenderson given the path it looks like Windows so they might have trouble with `head` and `tail`... (yeah, install cygwin)

Comment: @Spacedman good point. I believe you can install coreutils inc. `head` and `tail` on Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm maybe easier than cygwin?

Comment: I had a similar issue the other day and fixed the file in notepad++ (but it was only a few hundred meg). If you don't want to install cygwin etc, perhaps one of these editors will open your files? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded GVIM to edit the file and found the problem in line 2557. Turns out ampersand was encoded as &amp; with the problem being the semicolon, which is my seperator. I changed it to &, and ran the code again. Of course it just pointed out the next line that contains the same error. So right now I'm trying to do a search and replace all with GVIM, which sounds like something that should be easy, but it's just not doing it. At least I found a way to work on the problem now - just need to try a bit more.

Comment: OK, gave up on GVIM because I couldn't get it to find and replace all occurences of the problem. Moved on to a trial version of SlickEdit, which did the job. Had to search and replace a bunch of different encodings containing the semicolon, then had to locate (via R's error message) a bunch of other faulty lines, that had a semicolon missing. Finally I was able to read it in less than a minute using fread. Thanks for all the suggestions - they were all correct in pointing me to solve the problem by editing the file. I'd be happy to approve yours @LesH as the correct answer as it helped me out

Comment: That's kind, but it was a group effort and you figured out the final solution yourself. As much as I'd like the rep, you should answer your own question http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by installing [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/) and using it to edit the lines that caused the trouble. A few characters like ampersand, quotation marks, and apostrophes were consistently encoded to include semicolon - e.g. `&amp;` instead of just &. As semicolon was the seperator in the text document, this caused the problem in reading with `fread`.