# 10+GB file conversion from txt to csv

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, data-conversion, notepad

I have txt file which has 1400 columns and 3.1M rows.
I want to convert this file into csv. 
I tried doing it from excel - Data - from text option. 
The file was made but it had only 120k rows and all 1400 columns.

I am not sure how i should convert this whole file into csv?
It would be great to have help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the first few columns of the first few lines of how your data currently looks and how you want it to look and identify what OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I see you selected "notepad" tag. You should try: gVim ( https://gvim.en.softonic.com/ ). I used it to open 2gb files and it worked like a charm.
You can find more programs that allow you to open big files here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/159537/1564840

On the other hand, I suggest you to split that big txt file in multiple txt files. Then you can convert the smaller txt files one by one.