# Redshift COPY using JSONPath for missing array/fields

Tags: amazon-redshift, jsonpath

I am using the COPY command to load the JSON dataset from S3 to Redshift table. The data is getting loaded partially but it ignores records which has missing data(key-value/array) i.e. from the below example only the first record will get loaded.

Query:

> COPY  address from 's3://mybucket/address.json'
>   credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXX' 
>   maxerror as 250
>   json 's3:/mybucket/address_jsonpath.json';

My question is how can I load all the records from address.json even when some records will have missing key/data, similar to the below sample data set.

**Sample of JSON**

```
{
  "name": "Sam P",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "zip": "12345",
      "city": "Silver Spring",
      "street_address": "2960 Silver Ave",
      "state": "MD"
    },
    {
      "zip": "99999",
      "city": "Curry",
      "street_address": "2960 Silver Ave",
      "state": "PA"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "Sam Q",
  "addresses": [ ]
}
{
  "name": "Sam R"
}
```

Is there an alternative to [FILLRECORD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY-alphabetical-parm-list.html) for JSON dataset?

I am looking for an implementation or a workaround which can load all the above 3 records in the Redshift table.

Comment: Your `address_jsonpath.json` file content is really important here to provide an answer.

Comment: @RedBoy included the jsonpath file.

Comment: I tweaked your example JSON a little to make this simpler. For instance you had un-keyed objects as the values for name that I made into plain string values.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `FILLRECORD` equivalent for COPY from JSON. [It is explicitly not supported in the documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-json)

But you have a more fundamental issue - the first record contains an array of multiple `addresses`. Redshift's COPY from JSON does not allow you to create multiple rows from nested arrays.

The simplest way to resolve this is to [define the files to be loaded as an external table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html) and use our [nested data syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data.html) to expand the embedded array into full rows. Then use an `INSERT INTO` to load the data to a final table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS spectrum.partial_json;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.partial_json (
  name       VARCHAR(100),
  addresses  ARRAY<STRUCT<zip:INTEGER
                         ,city:VARCHAR(100)
                         ,street_address:VARCHAR(255)
                         ,state:VARCHAR(2)>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://my-test-files/partial_json/'
;

INSERT INTO final_table 
SELECT ext.name
     , address.zip
     , address.city
     , address.street_address
     , address.state
FROM spectrum.partial_json ext
LEFT JOIN ext.addresses address ON true
;
--  name  |  zip  |     city      | street_address  | state
-- -------+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------
--  Sam P | 12345 | Silver Spring | 2960 Silver Ave | MD
--  Sam P | 99999 | Curry         | 2960 Silver Ave | PA
--  Sam Q |       |               |                 |
--  Sam R |       |               |                 |
```

NB: I tweaked your example JSON a little to make this simpler. For instance you had un-keyed objects as the values for `name` that I made into plain string values.

Answer (score 1):

how about...

```
{
  "name": "Sam R"
  "address": ""
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.