# Open a 2GB xml file to understand the structure

Tags: php, mysql, windows, csv

OPEN NOT PARSE

I work with icecat xml files.
the current xml file is over 2GB. ( i have another one that is over 4GB )
There is nothing i am aware of to open it or read it.

I need to know the structure of the file so i can prepare my database.
unfortunately there is lack of documentation on icecat.

I prefer php and mysql to parse the data to a database.
The point is to get it read first to know the elements and it's attributes.
I simply do not know what is inside this huge file.

Comment: To check the structure, it may be easier to view the file yourself and see if that gives you enough to start reading the file automatically.

Comment: @NigelRen The whole point is i cannot get it to open

Comment: Have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files and see if any will work.

Comment: Not tried - but seems to have specific XML features - https://www.liquid-technologies.com/large-file-editor

Comment: Reading thru PHP works as usual (`fopen()` and `fread()`). Reading manually: just use a hex editor, they're usually able to open files unbound to any size. As for text editors: https://textpad.com/products/textpad/index.html easily eats i.e. 2.48 GiB files.

Comment: From the link provided to just READ the XML, the one that helped me was glogg. I will never delete that prog.