# How to open a very big file in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014?

Tags: ssms, ssms-2014

I have a file about ~9GB. It's a file extracted from an old MS SQL server and I need to import it to a new one. The file has no extension.

When I try to open it through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to open a large file to read it, which i assume that it is not the case, pick one of the text editors from this post:

- [Text editor to open big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

And in case you want to execute really big SQL scripts, you will have to do it through the Windows CMD (or Bash in case you are using Ubuntu for example) using SQLCMD, have a look at this:

- [Execute large scripts using SQLCMD](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4155/executing-large-scripts-in-sql-server-management-studio-with-insufficient-memory-failures/)

I hope this is what you are looking for!