# Open extremely large tab separated value (tsv) files (1.09 GB)

Tags: csv, notepad++, large-files

I'm trying to create a movie database from the dataset by IMDb (https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/) but I cant find a program that can open the very large file.

I've tried notepad, notepad++, VS Code and Excel. Only Excel can open the file but it does not show the complete dataset, only the first few thousand entries.

Does anyone know a program that can open large tsv files like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you ought to find a suitable editor in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EmEditor** can open very large CSV files. If tab-separated, click `Tab` in the **CSV/Sort** toolbar after you open the file.

[image: EmEditor - TSV]

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is probably already answered in [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

Still, I have no trouble opening files of a couple GB using VS Code or Atom. Not sure what is preventing those from working for you. Regardless of that, editors specifically suited for what you are trying to do can be found in the question I linked above.