# Getting EOF error while parsing when using eval()

Tags: python, string, list, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

In my dataframe I have a column named 'items'(list like string) like below

which is of type string. I want to convert this into a list .
I have tried various methods like ast.literal_eval ,eval etc..

```
import ast
import json
import numpy as np
null= None
d['items']=d['items'].apply(lambda x:ast.literal_eval(str(x)) if(np.all(pd.notnull(x))) else x )
```

By using ast.literal_eval method I am getting this error -ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000019AE0EA4B80>

By using eval() method I get this error - File "", line unknown SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

```
d['items']=d['items'].apply(lambda x:ast.literal_eval(str(x)) if(np.all(pd.notnull(x))) else x )
```

I have data with 139358 rows. In this data there are chances of having null, None or any other elements that could have caused this EOF error. I am assuming I had properly handled the nans using the if condition -('if(np.all(pd.notnull(x)))').

Please suggest any exception handling to do if that can help or let me know any solution that can convert these list-like-strings to lists.

Finally the datatype of records in items should be list but not strings (string to list conversion)
Thanks in advance!

> Answer: My data had Invalid JSON objects. So written an if statement
> to filter out the invalid JSONS

Comment: This is JSON, don't use `eval` to parse it, use `json` module.

Comment: How you handle exceptions is up to you: if some of those JSON strings are invalid, what do you want to do about it?

Comment: I am using Python 3

Comment: @buran that makes sense but i get this error though JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
You have any idea what it means?

Comment: @khelwood may be we can just not parse them and keep them as is and continue to the next record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure if the data is a perfect JSON or not

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json.loads) function:

```
import json
import numpy as np
d['items']=d['items'].apply(lambda x:json.loads(x) if(np.all(pd.notnull(x))) else x)
```

Comment: Yeah That gave me this error:JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the full question.  Let me take a look...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.  I'm creating the dataframe like this: `d=pd.DataFrame({'items':['...the string you posted exactly...']}, index=[0])`

Comment: Yeah true I think there is something underlying in the data that is conflicting the operation of json.loads..Any idea of tracing it ?

Comment: If could send your whole Python file that'd be great.

Comment: JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 651 column 27 (char 22037)
I get this error for another dataset. This dataset has around 239,789 records.

Comment: Holy cow, that's huge.  It's probably some control character or binary character or something like that, maybe `\u200b` or `\u200c`? Those seem to be common sometimes.  Probably viewing that file with `less` could show you what the problem is.   At any rate, it will always fail, no matter what method you use to parse the json, if the json is invalid.

Comment: How to trace which data(index number) caused the issue/error? Can you please let me know what is viewing the file with less.

Comment: @coder See [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159537).

Comment: You are right @hcaertnit , My data had invalid JSONs ... I corrected the code by filtering out invalid JSON objects and push only those which had valid JSON objects.

Comment: Great! Glad to here it's working.  Upvoted your answer as it's helpful too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below. Note sure if this will be helpful. This is Simple and I tried out with the input. Check and let me know.

```
`for i in df['items']:
   if isinstance(i, str):
      x=eval(i)
      df['items'][i]=x`
```

Comment: I get the same EOF error when I run your script. Following is the error I got ,<ipython-input-3-6fce17b8139b>:8: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  d['items'][i]=x Traceback (most recent call last):
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: As you are running in Jupyter notebook. Try to do from start. Try fresh once.