# How can I Add column Name in very Large Text file. Data is there in last column but I am missing the column Name

Tags: text, large-files

I Have a very large text file that I am unable to open in Notepad or excel. I am missing the column name in the last column. Data is there.

Comment: How big is the file? Can you use a hex-editor or lage-file-reader (e.g. programs which will only read, e.g. 1MB, at a time). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: Not understood the part with Text and Column. You Have A text file which you tried to open in Excel? Either it is not a text file or it is an excel file that you are trying to open using Notepad or some text editor. 
If it is `.txt` file, then use `Excel ->Data->Import from Text File` Option.
You can even try `Notepad++`or some HexEditors or even MS-Word

Comment: @Raky Your comment suggests you refuse to believe in the existence of 10GB CSV files...

Comment: I am familiar with read only programs. I need to edit the text file. Size is 80G +. I am missing the name of last column in the file. It is simple edit but due to the size of the file, I can't just open it in excel or Notepad ++

Comment: @Dai, I believe Everything is possible with Computers. The query is confusing. So My responses attempt to deal with both aspects of `.txt` and `.csv`. `.csv` is basically a text file with columnar data. When the @user3860954 mentioned text file with column, i presumed he is trying to open `.xls` or `.xlsx` with text editor. Please read my response again optimistically. Maybe you do not want to accept my response. Anyways you are boss of your opinion

Comment: @Raky _"I believe Everything is possible with Computers"_ - Counterexample: The Halting Problem.

Comment: @Raky _"When the @user3860954 mentioned text file with column, i presumed he is trying to open .xls or .xlsx with text editor"_ - but Excel `.xls` and `.xlsx` files are binary file formats, not text-based.

Comment: Hey @Dai, Try opening Excel file with Notepad. You will know. And Don't waste your time and energy on me but use it for the Helping people like user3860954.

Comment: _"Try opening Excel file with Notepad. You will know."_ - I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here...

Answer (score 0):

You need an editor that does not load the whole file into memory, only reading the section of the file you are viewing.

Have a look at [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files).

You could also look at [Liquid Editor - community edition](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/large-file-editor), which can read and edit huge files.