# How to read large text file on windows?

Tags: text-files, text-editor, large-files

I have a large server log file (~750 MB) which I can't open with either Notepad or Notepad++ (they both say the file is too large).

Can anyone suggest a program (for Windows) that will only read a small part of the file into memory at a time?

Or do I need to write my own app to parse this file?

Comment: Notepad is a just an Edit control.  :)

Comment: Your problem is already solved in this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Free Text Editor Supporting \*More Than\* 4GB Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102829/best-free-text-editor-supporting-more-than-4gb-files)

Comment: You can try this with less memory usage http://jenson.in/demos/open_giant_files_in_browser.php

Comment: @i_am_jorf, What do you mean by "edit control"?

Comment: I mean it is an [edit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: See Total Commander. It reads ANY file instantaneously.

Comment: Windows Powershell: Get-Content [PATH] -Wait

Answer (score 57, accepted):

try this...

[Large Text File Viewer](https://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=693)

By the way, it is free :)

But, I think you should ask this on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) instead

Comment: Serverfault? It's in beta. How do I get an invite?
And thanks for the viewer. Works a treat.

Comment: Works great for a 30Gb file. And the background style is terrible :)

Comment: Mhmm. It stops at the line 1378246... Is there a maximum ?

Comment: FWIW, I just tried twice to open a 1.08GB SQL file with this app and it froze on Windows XP.

Comment: This make use of local storage. Try this in Browser http://jenson.in/demos/open_giant_files_in_browser.php

Comment: It stops at 1/5 of the lines. Why?

Comment: Download from here if the original site is down. http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=693

Comment: I think the link broken ?

Comment: But this tool only shows a few lines. How would I search the large file?

Comment: tool didn't work for me...

Comment: Does any body know hot to open, say lines between 10000 and 20000? Not just N first lines.

Comment: The program holds when open more then 500 rows. :(

Answer (score 22):

If all you need is a tool for reading, then this thing will open the file instantly **http://www.readfileonline.com/**

Comment: Works great and I didn't have to download or install anything :)

Comment: I tried it using a 20MB text file and it breaks

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo I tried it with chrome and worked fine

Comment: Online editor for local files? Seriously?

Comment: @Win4ster Local applications like sublime/notepad++ load these files very slowly. I find this tool handy to scan large files quickly. Good for non-sensitive data.

Comment: @Win4ster The page states that the file is loaded locally via javascript.  I tried it with a 500mb file and it opened immediately and displayed pagination to move around.. including one to move to the end of the file instantly.

Comment: In my case, which is find out an Oracle schema in a 10GB dump it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

use [EmEditor](http://emeditor.com), it's pretty good, i used it to open a file with more than 500mb

Comment: This app worked great for me, but it does cost money.

Comment: @MosquitoMike 30 day free trial

Answer (score 9):

The integrated Text-**Viewer** of [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) can open huge files (>10GB) for viewing without any problems. It also provides different views, e.g. a Hex-View.

Comment: +1 it opened instantly my 300Mb SQL file and search is immediate. Since the interface is a bit tricky, I had to discover how to open the file viewer: just select the file and press F3.

Comment: How do you open Text-Viewer?

Comment: https://farmanager.com/index.php?l=en too

Answer (score 6):

Definitely **[EditPad Lite](http://www.editpadlite.com/download.html)** !

It's extremely fast not just while opening files, but also functions like "Replace All", trimming of leading/trailing whitespaces or converting content to lowercase are very fast.

And it is also very similar to [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ;)

Comment: Compared to all the other tools (not to mention the winner), this is my favorite.

Answer (score 6):

I have been using the [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) for quite some time for viewing large logs (some GBs) and it is working very well is very fast. There is a free version and a commercial Pro version.

They [say](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php) that it has

- Real-time file
- **Optimised real-time viewing engine View files of any size (> 2GB)**
- Scroll to any point in the whole file instantly
- View files over a network
- Configurable line wrapping
- Configurable TAB expansion
- Configurable font, including spacing and offset to maximise use of screen space

Another alternative is [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/). Viewing a several GBs file is no problem (little memory footprint), but attempting to open the text file in the Editing mode might take several GBs of RAM, so be aware of that. I am not aware of the file size limit that can be viewed/edited in Far.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. BareTail had no problem with 52GB file and provided very responsive scrolling. Far Manager opened the file too, but it has a quirky text terminal user interface.

Comment: FarManager is indeed quite a bit quirky, and its "edit" function needs to load the entire file... But solved the viewing/searching problem for me :) BareTail is perfect but it does not allow editing.

Answer (score 4):

[UltraEdit will do the trick](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html).

Answer (score 3):

I just used `less` on top of [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) to read a 3GB file, though I ended up using `grep` to find what I needed in it.

(`less` is `more`, but better.)

See this answer for more details on `less`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343576/1005039

Answer (score 2):

if you can code, write a console app. here is the c# equivalent of what you're after.
you can do what you want with the results (split, execute etc):

```
SqlCommand command = null;
try
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("XXXX"))
    {
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) command.Connection.Open();
        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt"))
        {
            String line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                command.CommandText = line;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.Write(" - DONE");
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Let the user know what went wrong.
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) command.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need ADO.NET to read a file from the File System?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to promote my own stuff (well, not really), but [PowerPad](http://quickmediasolutions.com/software/powerpad/) can open very large files.

Otherwise, I'd recommend a hex editor.

Comment: The link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

While Large Text File Viewer works great for just looking at a large file (and is free!), if the file is either a delimited or fixed-width file, then you should check out [File Query](http://www.agiledatasoftware.com/products.html).  Not only can it open a file of any size (I have personally opened a 280GB file, but it can go larger), but it lets you query the file as though it was in a database as well, finding out any sort of information you could want from it.

It is not free though, so it is more for people that work with large files a lot, but if you have a one-off problem, you can just use the 30-day trial for free.

Answer (score 0):

GnuUtils for Windows make this easy as well. In that package are standard UNIX utils like cat, ls and more. I am using cat filename | more to page through a huge file that Notepad++ can't open at all.

Answer (score -3):

You should try [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com), it can read a file of that size.

It's free to evaluate (you can evaluate indefinitely)

Comment: While this can indeed open a 750MB file, it's not a good answer because this program attempts to load the whole file into memory, so it will work exactly as well as trying to open the file in Notepad (i.e. it will crash).