# how to open sql dump file in windows 7

Tags: sql

I have an sql dump file having 5 GB of data. if i am trying to open by using textpad or notepad it is not opening.

Could you please suggest is there any free software is available to open such a big file around 5 GB of data.

i am using windows 7.

Best Regards,
Srinivas G

Comment: Do you really need to *look* at it? If so just google *windows huge file viewer*

Answer (score 0):

You can use different softs, but i never test for this size...

- [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)
- [How to read large text file on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846475/how-to-read-large-text-file-on-windows)

Have nice day,
Liberateur.