# Editor could not be initialized. Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, eclipse-kepler

I have one Heapdump file of size 247mb. I have installed MAT in my eclipse 
(both kepler/Luna) and had changed Xmx size to -Xmx1024m. But while opening the heap dump its always throwing below exception

"Editor could not be initialized. Java heap space"

Please share anybody has any solution regarding this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Viewing large XML files in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692329/viewing-large-xml-files-in-eclipse)

Comment: This is a bug See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294093