# Text Editor for gigabyte sized files

Tags: text-editor, bigdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

I saw [text editor to open big text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files) but that question referred to megabyte sized files. I work with 7GB csv files and find that even vim and gedit take a long time to open up.

What text editor do you use for for gigabyte sized files?

Appreciate any advice I can get.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: This should be at least a similar question or even linked as it was asked more than 2 years before this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102829/best-free-text-editor-supporting-more-than-4gb-files

Comment: try this http://jenson.in/demos/open_giant_files_in_browser.php

Answer (score 2):

don't know about others but i use vim (on windows) for editing GB files and it works every time. http://vim.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [total commander](http://www.google.com.np/search?q=total+commander&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)